# Handling zlib compressed json data between C++ Qt and javascript using webchannel

Tags: javascript, c++, qt5, zlib, pako

I'd like to share my knowledge on this process since it does not seem to be trivial and had to spend some time to figure it out. Hope this will be a useful manual.

## The problem:

There is a QT application, that sends large amount of data to be plot using PlotlyJS using QWebChannel. The data contains about 20 million datapoints. After some investigation it turned out that the bottleneck is the `QWebChannel` data transfer. One possible solution I figured is to compress the data before putting on the channel. The biggest issue I faced was converting the inflated data back to json in a fast manner and how to use js pako zlib compressor to inflate.

I always received

```
Uncaught unknown compression method
```

error after various modifications.

The solution I came up with, can be seen in the answer section.

Comment: Please note that this is a QA site, where users posts distinct questions and answers. If you had a problem that you solved, and think the solution might be helpful for others, then follow the QA format, by posting a question followed by a separate answer.

Comment: Also please take some time to refresh  [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ah my apologies. I updated it. I hope this is a better format. And thanks for the links I will go through them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The solution:

Note: This code does not contain the whole setup of web channel, but only the handling of the data between QT and JS.

### QT C++

The important thing is that js `pako.inflate()`  does not understand  the header generated by `qCompress` hence the `Unknown compression method error`. The header contains four bytes, that at least in my case were 0-s. Trimming them fixes the error.

```
QString compressJson(const QJsonObject &jsonObj)
{
    QJsonDocument doc(jsonObj);
    QString strJson(doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));
    QByteArray data = qCompress(strJson.toUtf8());
    // Remove the first four bytes, so that the external (js zlib decompressor understands the size header)
    // Leaving the leading 4 bytes in place will cause "unknown compression method" on the js side.
    data.remove(0, 4);
    return QString(data.toBase64());
}
```

```
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;

QJsonObject getPlotDataJson()
{
    // generate plotly digestable json data
}

SomeClass::SomeClass(QObject *pParent)
    : QObject
{
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    m_data = compressJson(getPlotDataJson());
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    qDebug() << "SomeClass::compress: " << duration.count() << " usecs";
}
```

Don't forget to set your data you want to share with `QWebChannel` as `Q_PROPERTY`

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class SomeClass: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString plotData MEMBER m_data)
public:
    explicit SomeClass(QObject *pParent = nullptr);
    QString m_data;
};
```

### JS Vanilla

```
/* Using FileReader to read very large data efficiently */
function largeuint8ArrToString(uint8arr, callback) {
    var bb = new Blob([uint8arr]);
    var f = new FileReader();
    f.onload = function(e) {
        callback(e.target.result);
    };

    f.readAsText(bb);
}

//! Decompresses zlib compressed plot data
function inflateData(data)
{
    // 1. Decode from base64
    var strData = atob(data);
    // 2. Convert to to js bytearray so that pako zlib inflate can understand the data
    const charData = strData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0); });
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(charData);
    // 3. Decompress
    return pako.inflate(bytes)
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
var startTime0 = performance.now()
new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
        var plotDataInflatedBytes = inflateData(channel.objects.SomeClass.plotData)
        largeuint8ArrToString(plotDataInflatedBytes,function(text){
                var mapped = JSON.parse(text)
                // ... your code to process the data
        });

        var endTime0 = performance.now()
        console.log(`new QWebChannel() exec time ${endTime0 - startTime0} milliseconds`)
    });
});
```

### Edit:

Formerly used simple loop to convert binarray to string:

```
let binArrayToString = function(binArray) {
    let str = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < binArray.length; i++) {
        str += String.fromCharCode(binArray[i]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

is replaced with a more efficient method using FileReader

```
function largeuint8ArrToString(uint8arr, callback) {
    var bb = new Blob([uint8arr]);
    var f = new FileReader();
    f.onload = function(e) {
        callback(e.target.result);
    };

    f.readAsText(bb);
}
```

## Conclusion:

Besides fixing the errors this code allowed me to plot the data in about 10 seconds instead of 30 min+. I also noticed that the performance still drops quite a bit if I double the cell count because of the `binArrayToString` mapping, so it is still the bottleneck.

## References:

[Uint8Array to string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936984/uint8array-to-string-in-javascript)

[How to zlib compress a QByteArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810897/how-to-zlib-compress-a-qbytearray)

[How to use pako.js javascript? Pako is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882741/how-to-use-pako-js-javascript-pako-is-not-defined)